# You cannot/should not initialize the payer account as a program account

Tags: anchor, typescript, anchor-client, error

I'm creating a basic staking contract and just trying to initialize the pool where the reward tokens will be held. I'm receiving the following error:

`TryingToInitPayerAsProgramAccount. Error Number: 4101. Error Message: You cannot/should not initialize the payer account as a program account.`

I really don't think i'm initializing the payer account as a program account? Here is the Initialize context

```
#[derive(Accounts)]
#[instruction(bump: u8)]
pub struct Initialize<'info> {
    #[account(mut)]
    pub owner: Signer<'info>,
    #[account(init, payer = owner, space = StakingPool::LEN + 8)]
    pub staking_pool: Account<'info, StakingPool>,

    pub stake_token_mint: Box<Account<'info, Mint>>,

    #[account(
        seeds = [
            b"vault".as_ref(),
        ],
        bump,
    )]
    pub token_vault: SystemAccount<'info>,

    #[account(
        init_if_needed,
        payer = owner,
        associated_token::authority = token_vault,
        associated_token::mint = stake_token_mint,
    )]
    pub vault_ata: Box<Account<'info, TokenAccount>>,

    pub system_program: Program<'info, System>,
    pub token_program: Program<'info, Token>,
    pub associated_token_program: Program<'info, AssociatedToken>,
}
```

And here is the frontend call

```
  const [stakingPoolPDA, bump] = PublicKey.findProgramAddressSync(
    [Buffer.from(Anchor.utils.bytes.utf8.encode('vault'))], // Adjust with actual seeds
    programId
  );

//   console.log('stakingPoolPDA', stakingPoolPDA.toString());

  const vaultAta = getAssociatedTokenAddressSync(
    goldMintAddress, 
    stakingPoolPDA, 
    true 
  );
      const ix = await program.methods
        .initialize(bump)
        .accounts({
          stakeTokenMint: goldMintAddress,
          tokenVault: stakingPoolPDA,
          vaultAta: vaultAta,
        })
        .instruction();
      const transaction = new Anchor.web3.Transaction();
      transaction.add(ix);
      let signature = await sendTransaction(transaction, connection, {
        skipPreflight: true,
```

the actual instruction implementation is just setting some initial values for the stake pool:

```
    pub fn initialize(ctx: Context<Initialize>, bump: u8) -> Result<()> {
        msg!("Instruction: Initialize");
        msg!("before staking pool");
        let staking_pool: &mut Account<'_, StakingPool> = &mut ctx.accounts.staking_pool;
        staking_pool.owner = ctx.accounts.owner.key();
        staking_pool.staking_token_mint = ctx.accounts.stake_token_mint.key();
        staking_pool.total_staked_amount = 0;
        staking_pool.total_reward_amount = 0;
        staking_pool.total_user_count = 0;
        staking_pool.reward_per_second = 0;
        staking_pool.bump = bump;

        Ok(())
    }
```

I'm thinking this has to be an issue with something not directly related to the error message, as i'm not initializing the owner/payer anywhere in my code. On the frontend, i'm only passing in the accounts that anchor can not infer (signer, system program, etc). But even when i explicitly pass in all the accounts i'm getting the same error

Answer (score 4):

It looks like you didn't provide the `staking_pool` account:

```
    #[account(init, payer = owner, space = StakingPool::LEN + 8)]
    pub staking_pool: Account<'info, StakingPool>,
```

The account is missing in your instruction.

```
      const ix = await program.methods
        .initialize(bump)
        .accounts({
          stakeTokenMint: goldMintAddress,
          tokenVault: stakingPoolPDA,
          vaultAta: vaultAta,
        })
        .instruction();
```

Comment: I thought I wouldn’t have to explicitly provide the staking_pool account since it is being initialized in the smart contract when that instruction is called (hence the init annotation). Is my logic incorrect here? If so, how would I know what address to pass in?

Comment: You do have to explicitly provide it. You probably want to include a `seed` and `bump` constraint in your `staking_pool` `#[account(init...)]` line to ensure that you only pass a valid PDA from the client.

Comment: Hm okay thank you. I was under the impression that I didn’t want staking_pool to be a PDA though? That’s why I initialized it with a set amount of space in the context. Not sure why I would want that particular account to be a PDA when I already have token_vault as a PDA to handle things like reward distribution and management

Comment: Following up, turning staking_pool into a PDA and then explicitly passing the account from the client ended up working! Thanks for the help. There were a couple other small things, but that was the core issue

Answer (score 2):

if it's not fixed yet, and you could share the repo i can maybe help you better.

But from just your initialize context:

You are missing your owner ATA. Should be something like this :

Ex:

```
  #[account(
    mut,
    associated_token::mint = stake_token_mint,
    associated_token::authority = owner
)]
pub owner_ata: Account<'info, TokenAccount>,
```

Also if you are dealing with SPL tokens you vault account cant be a system account.

Ex: A system account has no data therefore can only transact with native Sol.

Also seems to be an error with ur seeds

```
b"vault".as_ref(),
```

perhaps u meant

ex:

```
seeds=[b"vault", owner.key().as_ref()].
```

In your ts code looks like you are missing some accounts also.

Have a great day.